# A valid C++ statement?

Tags: c++

I couldn't find it online, so I thought I should ask here. Will

```
arr[0]++;
```

behave the same as

```
arr[0] = arr[0] + 1;
```

?

Comment: Assuming `arr` is an `int arr[]` , then yes

Comment: any cases where you failed to do this??

Comment: Please state the type of `arr`

Comment: @RyanHaining `Pirate`, obviously. Don't try that trick with the `--` operator. `Pirate`'s `--` overload burns the running computer to the waterline and keelhauls the user for daring to take *anything* from a `Pirate`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an integer it will.

But it depends on the type of **arr**.

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds!

Comment: where does this fail?? :\

Comment: @user007, a user-defined type may do different things for the increment operators and `operator +`.

Comment: Thanks anyway Alejandro :)

Comment: @user007 If `arr` is, for instance, an array of `list<T>::iterator`, then `++` is defined but `+ 1` is not.

Answer (score 1):

### In this case, yes. But, in other situations, no, it will not.

In general, with an array of object or number, it will call the post-increment operator, which can be different from a regular pre-increment operator--although post-increment may appear to just increment alone, in reality, it will increment the actual object BUT it will return a copy of the unincremented object. Beware of this small technicality.

Also, note that user-defined operator overloads may not follow these semantics at all.

Comment: The question has a semicolon at the end of the second code block, which implies that it is a complete statement. Assuming parallelism, both of the code blocks are therefore complete statements, which means that the return value is irrelevant. In this case, if `arr` is an `int` array, the two code blocks are the same.

Comment: @RedRoboHood But these expressions are not equivalent. Though they have the same behavior (or appear to have such), it's different for stacked or compound expressions that make use of post-increment.

Comment: You are correct, but Roguebantha made it clear by adding a semicolon that he is not asking about stacked or compound expressions.

Comment: @RedRoboHood Not to be picky, but the first block isn't a statement (no semicolon) AND I don't think it's good to give the impression that pre and post increment are the same.

Comment: Agreed. If you were to edit your answer to note that the differences do not apply to the exact situation given by the asker, it would be correct.